# Opencart Substract Stock doesn't work

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

All quantity of my product in the store are set to 10. And then my I tried to checkout . It seem the quantity of product still the same (Not Substract Stock).

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit a product in the admin panel and in the **Data** tab you will see a field called **Subtract Stock**.  Make sure it's set to **Yes**.